# data variable is returned as __ob__

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to have a line chart using vue-chart.js

I'm using the following vue component:

```
  Vue.component("line-plot", {
            extends: VueChartJs.Line,
            props: ["label", "data", "options"],
            mounted(){
                    fetch('api/data/monthlypaid')
                        .then(response => response.json()
                        .then(data =>{this.data = data;
                                      console.log(data);
                                      console.log(this.data); #replacing the statment above 
                                      }));
                    this.renderLineChart();
            }, 
            methods:{
                    renderLineChart: function () {
                        this.renderChart({
                            labels: this.data["DateReceived"],
                            datasets: [{
                                data: this.data ? this.data["AmountPaid"] : []
                                       }]

                            },
                            this.options )}
            },
            watch: {data: function () {
                              if (this._chart) {
                                 this._chart.destroy();
                              }
                              this.renderLineChart();
                          }
            }
    })
```

then I create my Vue app instance that contains the options for my chart.
The problem I have is with the data from the API. 
I have two `console.log` statments, the first returns the json data from the api, and the second is supposed to return the same thing since `this.data` is updated with `data` from the API call, however I get an `__ob__`. Any idea how to get the `this.data` to contain the json from the call to the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ahmad mentioned, it is not good practice to manipulate component props inside the component itself. However this wasn't my problem. my problem was much simpler than that.

my Line chart is a `chartjs` chart, so the `labels` and the `data` inside the `dataset` must be passed as an `array`. My API was sending data as JSON objects.
It is natural that 'Vuejs' converts the fetched data to an `__ob__`.

the solution was to either change the API output (which I did), or to loop througth the object which looks like `{0:200, 1:455, ..., 20:90}`. using a function like the following:

```
var group = {0:200, 1:455, 2:44, 3:355, 20:90}; # this is how my object looks like
var dt = [];
var numbers = Object.keys(group);
numbers.forEach(function(number) {
  var item = Object.values(group[person]);
  dt.push(item);
});
return dt
```

This returns the dt as an array which makes it usable with `chartjs`

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting a `prop`! And you're not using it!
You are not supposed to manipulate `props` in your vue component! Instead, use another data property with a different name :

```
 Vue.component("line-plot", {
        extends: VueChartJs.Line,
        props: ["label", "data", "options"],
        data(){
            return {
                 newData = this.data
                 // now you can manipulate this.newData
            }
        }
        mounted(){
                fetch('api/data/monthlypaid')
                    .then(response => response.json()
                    .then(data =>{this.newData = data;
                                  console.log(data);
                                  console.log(this.newData); #replacing the statment above 
                                  }));
                this.renderLineChart();
        }, 
        watch: {newData: function () {
                          if (this._chart) {
                             this._chart.destroy();
                          }
                          this.renderLineChart();
                      }
        }
})
```

Comment: thank you for your answer Ahmad, you're right on that part, I previously updated my data prop in the Vue instance (I didn't include that part here), and since it didn't work I tried to update the prop directly in the component (didn't know that I can't)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `__ob__: Observer` is part of Vue's reactivity system. If you don't see your API's response data along with the observer, it means that your `this.data` was not updated.

Look like you are trying to set `this.data` from a props, so it's possible that your parent component is changing `this.data`. I suggests that in your "line-plot" component, you create a variable, set it to `this.data`, then manipulate your variable instead:

```
data() {
    return {data2: this.data}}
},watch: {data2: function () {
    ...
}
```

Also, instead of console logging, you should get the Vue Devtool for your browser to inspect the value of your variables. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en